# How to write a generic SQL query to extract date in (YYYY-MM-DD) form which is compatible with all RDBMS (Oracle, SQL server, MySql, DB2 to name few)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a table where a student record is inserted and there is a column called joined_date which is of type `datetime2` in SQL Server and `TIMESTAMP(6)` in Oracle. I need to retrieve count of students who joined on a particular date and hence I need to group by `joined_date`.  For that, I need to extract only date (`YYYY-MM-DD`) from the `joined_date` column and it should be a generic SQL query.

Query: `select joined_date, count(*) from student group by joined_date`.

I can use `TO_CHAR(joined_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS joined_date` in Oracle.

Similarly we can convert in SQL Server with its own convert function. But I need a database agnostic generic query.

Comment: Which client to you use? Typically you can simply pass a **date(!)** value into the query and the driver (e.g. an ODBC driver) takes care about everything. Usually you don't need to convert it to a string.

Comment: I am using jdbcTemplate with plain sql to render the data in my Spring boot application. Agreed, I need not convert it to string but I need to extract only the date from timestamp/datetime2 column.

Comment: Unfortunately, short of gaining influence over the database system vendors, such that you can dictate that they actually agree to unify their date manipulation functions, you're not going to get a database agnostic query.

Comment: In the SQL standard you would use `cast(joined_date as date)`

Comment: If the column represents a date, why are you using datetime2 rather than date? Both MS and Oracle support those and that simple change would appear to solve your stated problem. But it would also prevent future problems in the MS side where a value in the column has a time portion that is not "00:00:00..." (presumably that is your assumption). In that case your grouping will not produce correct counts.

Comment: There are no date functions that are compatible with all databases.  Gosh, there probably aren't any that are even compatible with a majority of databases.

Comment: @SMor Datetime is used because the requirement is such that we need to capture the time as well and only for fetching this count of students who joined on a particular date, we need to trim the datetime to date.  
Anyways looks like there is no single way of handling this situation for different databases, I would go ahead with using different spring beans (services) based on dialect and create different sql query with respective trimming functions for each syntax.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your support, I have used spring beans to dynamically fetch different sql for different dialect (similar to the way hibernate works).

Answer (score 1):

More or less, every database has its own functions which do similar job. I'm not sure that you can do what you want, using a single query.

But, if you created a **view** in each of those databases and extracted desired value in the same format - for example, in Oracle

```
create or replace view v_student as
  select student_id,
         student_name,
         to_char(joined_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') joined_date
  from student;
```

then you'd run the same query in **all those databases**:

```
select joined_date,
       count(*)
from v_student
group by joined_date;
```

or

```
select student_name
from v_student
where joined_date = '2020-09-01'  --> this is a string!!!
order by student_name;
```

Of course, that "solves" this particular question. Date arithmetic would be difficult as dates are now represented as strings, but - that's what you asked for.

See if it helps.